# Intellisense is telling me that the UpdateMode property of my update panel needs to be set to Conditional, even though it is

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP.Net Update Panel which contains controls that I am trying to update from the code-behind file by setting the value of the controls to whatever I want them to be, and then calling the `Update()` method of the UpdatePanel.

I know that to call the Update() method, I need to set the UpdateMode property to conditional so this is what I have done, but I am getting the following error regardless:

> The Update method can only be called on UpdatePanel with ID 'UpdatePanel1' when UpdateMode is set to Conditional.

My Properties box looks like this:

[image: Properties]

My code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            myTimer.Interval = 1000;

            myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);

            myTimer.Start();
        }

        void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            var newGUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Label1.Text = newGUID;
            UpdatePanel1.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

My form looks like this:

[image: My ASPX Form]

My Markup is below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #form1
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" style="text-align: center" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Why isn't this working?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show your markup? I don't trust the VS designer.

Comment: This looks correct.  Have you tried rebuilding the solution and/or restarting VS?

Comment: Rebuilding did it, sort of, still not working but no more errors, when you say it looks correct do you mean just syntactically correct or it looks like it should achieve what I am trying to achieve? Or should I ask a new question? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you checking the [following tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx). The Timer control used is a `System.Web.UI.Timer` and not a `System.Timers.Timer` as in your code. Also the timer must be placed inside the update panel in order for it to trigger an AJAX call when the `OnTick` event is triggered:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script runat="server" type="text/c#">
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Panel refreshed at: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="ScriptManager1" />

        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer runat="server" id="Timer1" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" />
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Page not refreshed yet." id="Label1" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Label" id="Label2"></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

View the page in `Designer` mode and rename it, save and you should be good to go.  This is more than likely a cache issue with VS, toggling the designer mode forces the control to render in "Design" mode, so it should update the code behind the scenes to clear the error.